# Counting amount of db rows of a user using timestamp - Best approach?

Tags: php, mysqli

This might sound quite stupid, but whats the best approach to count a users db entries of today, so I can publish the most activate member with mysqli?

Thanks..

**Edited; Current code**

```
$promote_amount_posts = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT COUNT(rec_by_id) FROM posts LIMIT 1 "); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($promote_amount_posts);
$promote_amount_posts = $row['COUNT(rec_by_id)'];
$most_active_user_id = $row['rec_by_id'];
```

Lets say my user_id (which goes into the rec_by_id column) is 82392 and I created 20 posts. There should be atlease MY 20 posts in the 'posts' table. How do I fetch my user_id so I can echo it anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should return the count in `today_db_entries` as long as you have a `created` column and a `id` column - swap out those names for whatever your schema uses.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as today_db_entries 
FROM table 
WHERE created BETWEEN getdate() AND getdate()-1
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, could you take a look real quick?

Comment: I don't know why you added the `LIMIT 1` - but it shouldn't matter. You didn't add the date range WHERE clause? If you're doing it for all time that part shouldn't matter - you just specifically asked for "today" - Cheers